# Cumulative count for each ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Data:

```
Create table completion(user integer, count integer, completed date);
Insert into completion values (100,1,'2021-01-01'),(100,4,'2021-01-02'),(100,2,'2021-01-03'),
(101,4,'2021-01-05'),(101,5,'2021-01-08'),(102,1,'2021-01-04');
```

I want to produce 2 tables.

The 1st target is to get a cumulative count with respect to date for each individual ID:

```
user| cumulative | date
 100|          1 | 2021-01-01
 100|          5 | 2021-01-02
 100|          7 | 2021-01-03
 101|          4 | 2021-01-05
 101|          9 | 2021-01-08
 102|          1 | 2021-01-04
```

The 2nd target is to transform the date into number of days, counted from the minimum date for that ID:

```
user| cumulative | days passed
 100|          1 | 0
 100|          5 | 1
 100|          7 | 2
 101|          4 | 0
 101|          9 | 3
 102|          1 | 0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select c.*,
       sum(count) over (partition by user order by completed) as cumulative,
       datediff(completed, min(completed) over (partition by user)) as days_passed
from completion c;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a2db60b91157c9dd10a713e126370b76) is a db<>fiddle.